# Let two RPi's communicate over the internet

Tags: node.js, real-time, internet

I'm working on a little side project for which I would like to let two Raspberry Pi's communicate.

The idea is that they are both connected to the internet and have sensors and actuators (LED, motor etc) connected. Once RPi 1 recieves sensor data, I want RPi 2 to do something with that data (like blink a LED). AND the other way around. It doesn't need to be real time (altough that would be nice), a few seconds - 1min delay would not be a big problem.

I have a Ubuntu server running 24/7, so it would be possible to use that to communicate through. (With a database maybe?)

I have been looking at node.js/socket.io (as I have some experience with them) redis, zeromq (?), but I can't find a solution...

Does anybody know how to do this (easily?) or have some tips for where I could start looking? What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hello, Timon.  This question is not on topic as is defined in the help center.  Nothing about your question is specific to the Raspberry Pi.  My suggestion is to read up on REST APIs or socket programming.

http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method which is tailored to the Raspberry Pi would be to use my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library.

The pigpio [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) could be running on each Pi.  That would allow you to control each Pi using a [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) script running on your Ubuntu box.

Alternatively you could arbitrarily choose one of your Pis to be the master and run a script on that to control its and the other Pi's gpios.

I can't say that I'd want to do this over the internet though.  It would possibly be more sensible on a LAN.